# Method not found:

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Quando clico no botão salvar para executar o método, aparece o seguinte erro no console:

```
Jan 15, 2015 4:12:26 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
Advertência: Method not found: validacaoAjax.FuncionarioBean@37f7dcb0.salvaFuncionario()
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: validacaoAjax.FuncionarioBean@37f7dcb0.salvaFuncionario()
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:259)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:271)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jan 15, 2015 4:12:26 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
Grave: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: validacaoAjax.FuncionarioBean@37f7dcb0.salvaFuncionario()
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:259)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:271)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Arquivo XHTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:panel id="panel" header="Cadastro de funcionário">
        <p:messages id="msgResultado" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome: " />
            <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{funcionarioBean.nome}" requiredMessage="O nome é obrigatório" required="true" />
            <p:message for="nome" id="msgValidacaoNome" />

            <h:outputLabel for="funcao" value="Função: " />
            <p:inputText id="funcao" value="#{funcionarioBean.funcao}" requiredMessage="A função é obrigatória" required="true" />
            <p:message for="funcao" id="msgValidacaoFuncai" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton id="btnSalvar" value="Salvar" update="panel" actionListener="#{funcionarioBean.salvaFuncionario}"/>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Arquivo java:

```java
package validacaoAjax;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "funcionarioBean")
public class FuncionarioBean {

    private String nome;
    private String funcao;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getFuncao() {
        return funcao;
    }
    public void setFuncao(String funcao) {
        this.funcao = funcao;
    }

    public void salvaFuncionario(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Olá "+nome+" Você trabalha com"+funcao));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você importou a classe `ActionEvent` do pacote errado (AWT). Você deve importar a classe do pacote `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent` e não do `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`.

Esse erro é gerado porque o JSF procurou mas não achou um método apropriado com esse nome. Ele não soube como passar o parâmetro (`java.awt.event.ActionEvent`) do método `salvaFuncionario`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou aqui.

Comment: @user8465, se essa resposta é a correta para sua pergunta, por favor, marque-a como resolução para a resposta.

Comment: como que marca ?

Comment: @user8465, acredito que seja apenas marcar o "check" que tem abaixo da pontuação.